# Device assembly management

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a db of parts in an Access db.
Now I wish to create a kind of construction management.

Imagine to have in warehouse some pieces, and you have to assembly devices starting from them.

I wish to create a query in which I introduce group name and I get a kind of bill of material with available and requested quantities to assembly.

Example:
*Warehouse table* (already existing)

```
[code]¦[Quantity]
A¦3
B¦4
C¦0...
```

Device "Alpha" is made by (I don't know how to declare these devices composition)

```
[code of which _Alpha_ is made]¦[Quantity for mounting _Alpha_]
A¦2
B¦0
C¦1
```

I launch the query (as Input I'm going to pass "Alpha", the name of the device) and I get a table like

```
Device name: Alpha
[code]¦[warehouse qty]¦[required qty to be picked from warehouse]
A¦3¦2
B¦4¦0
C¦0¦1==> error: I can't assembly because 1 piece is missing
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a table or query an existing one?

Comment: The table about warehouse pieces is already existing, I'd like to know how to manage devices I can build assembling those pieces

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (no images). [mcve]

Comment: I edited the question. Do I need to write here that I updated or will you get a notification?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
    SELECT w.Code, w.Quantity,a.Quantity,
    WHEN w.Quantity < a.Quantity THEN "Not enough in warehouse" ELSE ""  AS Error          
    FROM Warehouse w
    INNER JOIN Alpha a ON a.Code = w.Code
```

Comment: I have 100 devices, so do I need to create 100 tables like `a`?

Comment: You could do, but it really depends are these devices going to have a live connection or are they going to be upload and download the data?

Comment: What do you mean as "live connection". Those devices are fixed in composition. Sometimes I add a new device or I modify a component inside of them. "Alpha" should be and input of the query, not something static. I have hundreds of devices with different names

Comment: Are the device going to have a live connection to the database or is the data going to uploaded and download?

Comment: And also does that query do what you need it to when working with just one device?

Comment: I'd use a live connection, and I'd call the query one device at a time.

Comment: You could try putting all the devices on one big table and write a big query to read all of them at once or put them on multiple tables and use a small query. At that point it becomes and a design choice and what you find easier to manage.